# haven't been travelling vs haven't travelled

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, difference

Could you please tell me the difference between the two following sentences?
When do I use the first one and when do I use the second one?
Are both of them correct?

> 1. I haven't been travelling for 3 years
> 2. I haven't travelled for 3 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically both of them are correct.
However, in negative sentences

```
2. I haven't travelled for 3 years
```

sounds more natural (or, on the contrary (1) sounds unnatural).

There's no need to use a progressive tense to describe something that you didn't do.

Comment: Thanks.
But what's the difference betwen them?

Comment: The difference is that (2) sounds more natural to talk about things that you haven't done for a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Serge, but you could say "I haven't been travelling for 3 years, only for 1 year" as an answer to the question: "Have you been travelling for 3 years?" or if someone says: "I heard you have been travelling for 3 years" and you want to convey that you haven't.